# ¿Saben si como en un input se eliminen los espacios y el texto quede sin espacios?

Tags: angular, typescript

Alguna parte necesito que me si alguien sabe me apoye en ese punto permítanme poner el input

```
                <div class="form-group">

                    <div class="input-group">

                        <span class="col-3 input-group-addon">Usuario: </span>

                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg col-8" 
                          name="nickname" formControlName="nickname"
                            placeholder="Ingresar usuario"  [ngModel]="null" required>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías intentar de la siguiente manera, lo cuál no permitirá que se ingresen datos en blanco en tu input:

```
<input 
  type="text" class="form-control input-lg col-8" 
  name="nickname" formControlName="nickname"
  placeholder="Ingresar usuario"  
  [ngModel]="null" required
  (keydown.space)="$event.preventDefault()">
```

Comment: Gracias, de la forma que indicaste, si funciona